# Oracle .oui Install Error

Tags: oracle, installation, redhat

When I'm trying to install Oracle on Linux Redhat 5 I get the error of `.oui at line 54  file permission denied.`

I gave permission to the .runInstaller file up to 777 but that did not help me.

I created the dir like /u01/app/oracle

Answer (score 0):

Check out the forum post below.  It goes through a series of steps regarding permissions, prerequisites, and user level to resolve the error you are getting:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1102139

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is:

1. Copy oracle installation in /home/oracle/database with oracle user
2. Change mod for all structure under database folder

   ```
   chmod -R 777 /home/oracle/ndatabase/
   ```
3. Call install script from database folder

   ```
   sh ./runInstaller
   ```